# Google App Engine Local Host Issue

Tags: python, google-chrome, google-app-engine, web-applications

I'm new to Google App Engine and I followed multiple video tutorials (One from Udacity) and for some reason I am unable to get it to run on the local host with the simple "Hello World" program.

I do have the Python SDK installed as well as the Google App Engine program installed. I did modify the YAML file so that it matches with my application (it did by default). When I click "run" in the Google App Engine launcher, it shows a yellow triangle caution sign next to the program I'm attempting to run.

When I type the `localhost:8080` in the search bar it says:

> This webpage is not available

I've also tried reinstalling both Python 2.7.9 and the Google App Engine and to no avail. In short I would like to understand why the program shows no content when I attempt to run it. Here are the log files if it's any help:

```
2015-03-14 18:36:21 Running command: "['E:\\Python\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\new_project_template']"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 83, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 79, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
2015-03-14 18:36:21 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the default `pythonw` on your system (`E:\Python\pythonw.exe`) is some version of Python 3.  That's where `execfile` is indeed not defined (and the GAE launcher's incompatible with Py3 in other ways, anyway, at this time).

To verify, run `E:\Python\python.exe` at a cmd prompt -- it should greet you with a version banner which I bet will mention Python 3.something.

**Where** did you (re-)install 2.7.9?  How's your `PATH` environment variable?  Likely with `E:\Python` **before** wherever 2.7.9 is installed.

Simplest might be to change your PATH so that wherever 2.7.9 is installed comes **before** `E:\Python`...!

Comment: You know I saw that in the log file and was tempted to change it but for whatever reason I didn't. I really appreciate the help(It's working seamlessly now) all I had to do was go into the settings of the Google App Engine and change the Python path from the default(On the E: drive which was Python 3) to the re installed path on the C: drive. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Divaglio, you're welcome!  Remember to **accept** the answer (click on the checkmark-shaped outline to the left of it) -- that's a key aspect of StackOverflow etiquette.